# Help with R code

Tags: r

I am a newbie at R and I'm stuck at the following code

```
$y=c(2.5,6.0,6.0,7.5,8.0,8.0,16.0,6.0,5.0,6.0,28.0,5.0,9.5,6.0,4.5,10.0,14.0,3.0,4.5,5.5,3.0,3.5,6.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,6.0,5.0,6.5,5.0,10.0,6.0,18.0,4.5,20.0)
x2=c(650,2500,900,800,3070,2866,7500,800,800,650,2100,2000,2200,500,1500,3000,2200,350,1000,600,300,1500,2200,900,600,2000,800,950,1750,500,4400,600,5200,850,5000)
x1=c(16.083,48.350,33.650,45.600,62.267,73.2170,204.617,36.367,29.750,39.7500,192.667,43.050,65.000,44.133,26.933,72.250,98.417,78.650,17.417,32.567,15.950,27.900,47.633,17.933,18.683,26.217,34.433,28.567,50.500,20.950,85.583,32.3830,170.250,28.1000,159.8330)
library(MASS) 
n=length(y)
X=matrix(nrow=n,ncol=2)
for(i in 1:n){X[i,1]=x1[i]}
for(i in 1:n){X[i,2]=x2[i]}
nbrun=0
gibbs=function(data,m01=0,m02=0,k01=0.1,k02=0.1,a0=0.1,L0=0.1,nburn=0,ndraw=5000)
{m0=c(m01,m02)
C0=matrix(nrow=2,ncol=2)
C0[1,1]=1/k01
C0[1,2]=0
C0[2,1]=0
C0[2,2]=1/k02
beta=mvrnorm(1,m0,C0)
omega=rgamma(1,a0,1)/L0
draws=matrix(ncol=3,nrow=ndraw)
while(-nburn < ndraw){ -nburn=-nburn+1
C1=solve(solve(C0)+omega*t(X)%*%X)
m1=C1%*%(solve(C0)%*%m0+omega*t(X)%*%y)
beta=mvrnorm(1,m1,C1)
a1=a0+n/2
L1=L0+t(y-X%*%beta)%*%(y-X%*%beta)/2
omega=rgamma(1,a1,1)/L1
if(-nburn>0){
draws[-nburn,1]=beta[1]
draws[-nburn,2]=beta[2]
draws[-nburn,3]=omega
}
}
return(draws)}$
```

whenever I run the code I get:"Error: object 'nburn' not found" and I don't understand why

Comment: R doesn't know the object `nburn`. You defined `nbrun`. Spelling is important in programming.

Comment: The site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your code fragment there is a variable called nbrun, later there is nburn ...

Comment: ty for that now I get:"Error in omega * t(X) %*% X : non-conformable arrays"

Comment: well, I'm not going to do _all_ your work, but it's a good bet that X isn't square and needs to be. (note it's a good idea to 'accept' answers that help you)